# How can i schedule local notification for Mon,Tue and Fri at 5PM in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift3

In swift 3, how can I schedule local notification for a particular day like Mon, Tue and Sat for a specific time like 5 PM?

Currently, I have schedule local notification for a time which I have set.

```
 let myOwnDate = Date()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
 let currentDate = dateFormatter.string(from: myOwnDate)
 let dateTime = currentDate + " " + self.btnTime.titleLabel!.text!
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"
 let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateTime)!

 localNotification.fireDate = date
 localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.weekday
 localNotification.alertBody = "Your alarm is ringing!"
 let app = UIApplication.shared
            app.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

But the problem is that this notification fires for all days.

Comment: are you working with any database ? or core-data

Comment: i am using sqlite

Comment: then do one thing just add date and time in your database and fetch that data in background and add notification according to data.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya But i think this is not right way

Comment: i know its not right way but your problem will be solve. one more thing that user did see that which day notification rise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the *repeatInterval* to

```
NSCalendar.Unit.weekOfYear
```

instead of weekday. Weekday will fire every day of the week.

You should also create 3 notifications like this, one for Monday, one for Tuesday and one for Friday. Each will repeat weekly.

Comment: There is no option like NSCalendar.Unit.week

Comment: You are right, that one was deprecated I think. Try weekOfYear.